# SharePoint Services 2.0 SP2 - upgrade to SharePoint Services 3.0 SP2

Tags: wss-3.0, wss-2.0, upgrade, environment

I'm working for a company that is using SharePoint.

The colleague that was in charge of SharePoint left the firm, and for the last 2-3 years he didn't do anything with it.

For that reason we are using SharePoint Services 2.0 SP2.

Now I would like to upgrade to the newer version. My plan is to upgrade to SharePoint Services 3.0 SP2.

I have around 50 users that are using SharePoint 24/7.

I don't have real experience in work with SharePoint, or with backup/restore.

Also, we are using SQL Server 2005 Pro.

Can someone explain to me how to make a backup of my current version (do I backup only SharePoint or SQL)?!

How do I build a test machine on which I can test migration/updates before making the same changes on the production machine (I would like to make a copy of my environment on different PCs (different hardware), and perform all tests on that PC)?!

What is the best way?

Answer (score 3):

Miroslaw.  What you are asking is not a question with one easy answer.  I would first suggest that you learn about the WSS 2.0 installation that you have, and how you can do effective backup and restores.  More info on WSS 2.0 can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb267377.aspx).

Then you need to look at the [upgrade](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303309.aspx) path and what 'gotchas' to look for.

It is not a trivial process to upgrade, but there are plenty of resources out there to help you.  If you need advice on any specfifc aspect of the upgrade then ask it as a seperate question on SharePoint Overflow as it is always difficult to answer really 'big' questions like this one.